# UICollectionView Crashes when Cell is Touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with a custom class subclassed to `UICollectionViewCell` showing pictures from within the app.  It loads fine, but if any cell is even barely touched, the app crashes.  There is no error message in the Console, and nothing shows if I put in an Exception breakpoint either.  The code for the view controller containing the Collection View is:

```
#import "ImagePicker.h"
#import "CMFGalleryCell.h"
@interface ImagePicker ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArray;
@end

@implementation ImagePicker
@synthesize dataArray, collectionView;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Choose Image";
    [self loadImages];
    [self setupCollectionView];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
-(void)setupCollectionView {
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CMFGalleryCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    [flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
    [flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
    [self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.dataArray count];
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CMFGalleryCell *cell = (CMFGalleryCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *imageName = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setImageName:imageName];

    [cell updateCell];
    return cell;
}
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Chose%ld", (long)indexPath.row);
}
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(185, 185);
}
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1.0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1.0;
}

// Layout: Set Edges
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    // return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,8,0,8);  // top, left, bottom, right
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);  // top, left, bottom, right
}
-(void)loadImages {
    NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"inviteimages"];
    self.dataArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sourcePath error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.dataArray);
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

The custom Cell is:

```
#import "CMFGalleryCell.h"

@interface CMFGalleryCell()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@end

@implementation CMFGalleryCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CMFGalleryCell" owner:self options:nil];

        if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1) {
            return nil;
        }

        if (![[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) {
            return nil;
        }

        self = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)updateCell {

    NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"inviteimages"];
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", sourcePath, self.imageName];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filename];

    [self.imageView setImage:image];
    [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

}

@end
```

What is going on causing it to crash if a cell is touched?  If I touch the space between cells, I can get it to scroll, but any touch at all of the cell crashes.

Screenshot of crash without zombies:
[image]

Screenshot of crash with zombies:

[image]

Comment: can you please post the crash reason

Comment: @T_77 If you actually read the question, you would see where I said "There is no error message in the Console, and nothing shows if I put in an Exception breakpoint either"

Comment: Sometimes you get a crash reason if you use instruments . Try to run the app with Zombie and see what happens while crash

Comment: @T_77 Never knew that.  Did it and got this ` *** -[ImagePicker retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fab6620a020
`

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the stacktrace when it crashes ?

Comment: You need to disable Zombies first

Comment: Well, we don't see anything... click on the square between the 2 lines on the bottom left. We will need the code you use to present the picker too.

Comment: @deadbeef when i went to get the code used to present picker I saw the issue, I was releasing the view controller in that.  Got rid of the line and working fine.

Comment: Manually ?!! Are you nor using ARC ? If not you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you app will crash when cell is touched but you haven't implemented the cell select delegate method but written only cell deselect delegate method. Try this

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And insert a breakpoint inside the same method to debug. If break point is not called then something else is the problem

Comment: Can you post your crash report. Or can you tell what your compiler shows about the error message

Comment: `*** -[ImagePicker retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fab6620a020`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe problem is in your View Controller class:

`@property` link to `ImagePicker` can be `weak`, and you, for example, remove it from superview. After this, `ImagePicker` object will be deallocated.
Try to replace

`@property (weak, nonatomic) ImagePicker *someImagePicker`

with

`@property (strong, nonatomic) ImagePicker *someImagePicker`

Can you share code from your `UIViewController`?